# Pass an existing variable int url

Tags: php, html

What I am trying to do is add a variable to an url.  I will try to explain, On my index page, when a user selects a department, i assign that department to end of the url and directs to new page..  On the new page after button is clicked, I would like to place the first variable at the end of the link but also a new variable.`http://www.example.com?$ExistingVariable&newVariable=Newvalue`

Comment: is there a way to just put it in a link form exp.```www.example.com?$variable&new=old```

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding the question.  Maybe it will help if you show the urls you want at each step of the process as you would expect them to be.

Comment: Ok the here are the Urls;  ```http://www.example.com``` user clicks department new Url is passed on to next page with the new variable; ```http://www.example.com?newVar=orange``` new page on a button click i would like to put ```http://www.example.com?$newVar``` on the previous page i will have used the ```$product_colour = $_GET['newVar']; ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define the two variables: $ExistingVariable and $newVariable, then put the value of your ExistingVariable and newVariable into these two variables and finally add them into the URL by following this process:

```
  <a href="http://www.example.com?ExistingVariable=<?php echo $ExistingVariable;?>&newVariable=<?php echo $Newvalue;?>">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution if you to append to a redirect header, or you can still print it out:

```php
<?php
// let's say I want to add $a and $b to url
$a = "hello a";
$b = "hello b";

$join_str = function($key, $value){
    // urlencode to handle spaces and other special chars in your value
    return $key . '='. urlencode($value);  
};
$compact_arr = compact("a", "b");
$query_arr = array_map($join_str, array_keys($compact_arr), compact("a", "b"));

$query_str = implode("&", $query_arr);

// here is your url string
echo $query_str;
// a=hello+a&b=hello+b
```

Not as elegant as I want it but should get the job done.

Answer (score 1):

Just grab the existing variable using a GET, create a new one, and tack it on.  (Note this may not be the most elegant solution)

```
http://www.example.com?existing_variable=ExistingVariable
```

(note, don't give it a $)

so on this page:

```
$existing_variable = $_GET['existing_variable'];
```

Then assign a new variable:

```
$newVariable = 'newVariableValue';
```

Then construct your link like you did in the first place:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com?existing_variable=<?php echo $existing_variable; ?newVariable=>&newVariable=<?php echo $newVariable; ?>">Your link text</a>
```